# PHPUnit @expectedException with assertion

Tags: exception, phpunit, assertion

I am trying to expect an assertion failure and then the set of all my tests should not throw a failure.

```
/**
* @expectedException Exception
*
*/
public function testGetAtlantisDriver(){

    $object = null
    $this->assertNotNull($object);

}
```

But this is not working.

What I get is an assertion failure

> Failed asserting that null is not null.

I expected the tests would be pass without failure. What did I wrong or what can I do to make this pass?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The @expectedException annotation is used when your code is supposed to throw an exception. This does not include the PHPUnit assertion errors. You can't expect an assertion failure.

If it worked the way you suggest there would be problems:
Suppose you have a test method with some assertions and then some code that throws an exception with an @expectedException. Then if some of the assertions failed you would not know, as the test would still pass.

You can't make a test pass if an assertion is not right, and that's what is expected from a testing Framework.

You can only mark a test as skipped with

```
$this->markSkipped("reason for skipping");
```

if you want to temporarily disable a test.